# RoR: Creating/Updating: Showing validation errors while preserving previous values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic model in which i have specified some of the fields to validate the presence of. in the create action in the controller i do the standard:

```
@obj = SomeObject.new(params[:some_obj])

if @obj.save
  flash[:notice] = "ok"
  redirect...
else
  flash[:error] = @obj.errors.full_messages.collect { |msg| msg + "<br/>" }
  redirect to new form
end
```

however when i redirect to the new form, the errors show, but the fields are empty. is there a way to repopulate the fields with the entered values so the errors can be corrected easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `render :action => :new` rather than redirecting.

Comment: The reason behind this is so that you keep the object in memory rather than creating a new object; the redirect starts an entirely new request.

Comment: The downside is that the form for creating a SomeObject now has two URLs:
/some_objects/new  # for the first form
/some_objects      # after a failed POST

Not much can be done about it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Capture `@obj` in the flash hash as well, and then check for it in the `new` action.

```
@obj = SomeObject.new(params[:some_obj])

if @obj.save
  flash[:notice] = "ok"
  # success
else
  flash[:error] = @obj.errors.full_messages.collect { |msg| msg + "<br/>" }
  flash[:obj] = @obj
  # redirect to new form
end
```

In `new`:

```
@obj = flash[:obj] || MyClass.new
```